# onClick multiple button - Android

Tags: java, android, onclick

hello I'm new to android and I have a problem with multiple button first I implemented multiple button in my MainActivity and it is work with me now I create another activity and implement the same what i do in the mainActivity in the new activity I have a multiple button in this activity

**the new Activity (Activity6.class):**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class Activity6 extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.adminbackdoor);

    Button ee = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
    Button ff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    Button gg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
    Button hh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
    ee.setOnClickListener(this);
    ff.setOnClickListener(this);
    gg.setOnClickListener(this);
    hh.setOnClickListener(this);


}
@Override
public void onClick (View vv){

    switch (vv.getId()) {

        case R.id.button12:

            Intent e = new Intent(Activity6.this, Admin1.class);
            startActivity(e);


            break;

        case R.id.button9:

            Intent f = new Intent(Activity6.this, User1.class);
            startActivity(f);

            break;

        case R.id.button10:
            Intent g = new Intent(Activity6.this, Teacher1.class);
            startActivity(g);

            break;

        case R.id.button11:
            Intent h = new Intent(Activity6.this, Class1.class);
            startActivity(h);

            break;


        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

**Admin1.class**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Admin1 extends AppCompatActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.admin);

}
}
```

**User1.class**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class User1 extends AppCompatActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.adminuser);

}
}
```

activity Teacher1.class and Class1.class have the same with Admin1.class and User1.class but with different layout. 
Note: I add all the activities in manifest like this:

```
    <activity android:name=".Activity6"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Admin1"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Class1"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Teacher1"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".User1"></activity>
```

adminbackdoor.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:text="العمليات"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="140dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_width="231dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round"
    android:text="admin"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="231dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round"
    android:text="user"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="231dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round"
    android:text="teacher"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_width="231dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round"
    android:text="class"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

and onClick does not work with me I do not know what is the problem ??
if I run the application and click on the button they did not work ( go to another layout )

Comment: what do you mean: `and onClick does not work with me`

Comment: You need to try and be a little more clear on what the problem is that you have. Currently, your question is quite unclear.

Comment: I mean if I run the application and click on the button they did not work ( go to another layout

Comment: Add XMl code maybe you are doing something wrong here.!
or maybe there is another layout on your layout which is not allowing you to click other layout.!

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi I add XML code but what you mean by maybe there is another layout on your layout which is not allowing you to click other layout ?? how do I know if they allow or not ??

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should extend `Activity` and not `AppCompatActivity`.

And one thing I can recommend is to use the click listener like this in this situation:

```
 Button ee = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
        ee.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent e = new Intent(Activity6.this, Admin1.class);
                startActivity(e);
            }
        });
```

Comment: `AppCompatActivity` is recommended for supporting compatibility

Comment: I can use the click listener like what you do because I have switch